# PHP only reading one $_POST value

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using AJAX to send some variables to a PHP form that will process them and put them into session variables. In the code below, I am trying to get data from two POST variables.

If I leave both as they are, none will work. If I comment out one, the other will work, and vice versa. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is the AJAX that sends data to the PHP page to be processed:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         async: false,
         data:
             {
                 from_date: from_date,
                 job_no: job_no,
             }, 
         url: 'pnf_post.php', //send variables to this page to be processed
         success: function(data){  
             oTable2.fnReloadAjax('FE_resolved_pnfs.php'); //reload datatables
            },
         error: function(){
             console.log(data);
             alert('Error');
            }

        });
```

Here is the code that processes the AJAX data:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['job_no']))
    {
        $_SESSION['Job_Num'] = $_POST['job_no'];
        $_SESSION['Search_By_Date'] = "NO";
    }

if(isset($_POST['from_date']))
    {
        $_SESSION['From_Date'] = $_POST['from_date'];
        $_SESSION['Search_By_Date'] = "YES";  
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please show the results of `var_dump($_POST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have set both `from_date` and `job_no` in the post data
2. You check if key `from_date` or `job_no` exists
3. Obviously they both exist
4. You set `Search_By_Date` first to `NO` then to `YES` so it's always `YES`

You might want to check if the value evaluates to true or false instead of using `isset` which checks the existence of the *key* in the array.

@jk. Trailing comma is not a problem for modern browsers.

Comment: I am new to php/jquery and so I think I have misunderstood how POST works. My thinking is that by using isset, I am checking to see if any data has been passed in the variable. I will change the code to just look at what is inside the variable

Comment: @user3101337 You have specified the post data as `{from_date: from_date, job_no: job_no}`, so that both will be included. They may have a value of `null` or `undefined`, but they exists, so isset() will return true for both keys.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the comma here:

```
job_no: job_no,
```

And change it to:

```
job_no: job_no
```

Full snip:

```
data:
    {
     from_date: from_date,
      job_no: job_no
     },
```

Comment: I had removed a couple of variables to make it easier to read and forgot about the comma. Good eye, though!